# How to get Absolute coordinates (in relation to canvas) after a Group Zoom in fabric js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have been struggling with this problem now for few hours now.. here's the scenario

There are multiple independent elements on the canvas

1. Select multiple objects by mouse drag
2. Resize the group
3. Now click away from group (to discard group, as it was only a temporary
   grouping)
4. Now click on any individual element..

**Issue:** it looses the new scale and position which it got as a result of group scale action.

Following is what I tried doing, to correct it:

1. Listen to object:scaling event
2. Here set the correct scale, for individual elements in the group (this solves the scaling issue)

But, **Still, Issue:** No way to set the coordinates of individual elements, as I am unable to get the new coordinates of the element, neither in relation to group (so that I can compute) nor the absolute coordinates (in relation to canvas)

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

it would help if you could make jsfiddle example.in this site we use them alot , in order to show what we need.
it is strange though that your objects are losing the position and scale.maybe the way you create them at first.